# Selecting a specific line in a list of strings in python

Tags: python, html, string, list, web-scraping

I have a string that prints the following saved as a list. this is how I have the list created in the current format

```
for ticker_list in ticker_list_items:
    ticker = ticker_list.contents[0]
```

```
<div id="T-THO">
<div class="confirm icon-check" title="Last confirmed on 2/18/2020"></div>
<div class="company" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">Thor Industries, Inc.</div>
<div class="ticker" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">THO</div>
<div class="time" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">6:45 AM ET</div>
<div class="epstitle" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">EPS:</div>
<div class="revtitle" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">Rev:</div>
<div class="estimate" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">$0.76</div>
<div class="revest" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">$1.79 B</div>
<div class="revgrowthprint">38.7%</div>
```

This is saved as a list with 6 other strings in a very similar format. my goal is to extract the data from that first line containing 'div id...' and save it as a new list.

some of the strings in this list have more than one instance of 'div id...'

I am attempting to do this in a for loop but am really lost with ways to save a line based on the first "x" number of characters.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/web-scraping-101-with-python-beautiful-soup-bb617be1f486

Comment: Can't you use an HTML parser?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this data comes from a website, in which case the simplest way would be to use some parser designed for that (i.e. BeautifulSoup). Alternatively you can define some pattern you are looking for and parse out the data yourself using a module like `re` which comes standard with python.

```
import re

ticker_list = ["""<div id="T-THO">
<div class="confirm icon-check" title="Last confirmed on 2/18/2020"></div>
<div class="company" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">Thor Industries, Inc.</div>
<div class="ticker" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">THO</div>
<div class="time" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">6:45 AM ET</div>
<div class="epstitle" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">EPS:</div>
<div class="revtitle" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">Rev:</div>
<div class="estimate" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">$0.76</div>
<div class="revest" onclick="javascript:location.href='stocks/tho'">$1.79 B</div>
<div class="revgrowthprint">38.7%</div>""", """<div id="Section 2">"""]

title_list = []
for ticker in ticker_list:
    name_div = re.search('<div id=".+?">', ticker).group() # matches <div id="T-THO">
    title = re.search('".+?"', name_div).group()[1:-1] # matches "T-THO" and gets all but " chars
    title_list.append(title)

print(title_list)
```

Results in:

> ['T-THO', 'Section 2']